# No WebApplicationContext found not in DispatcherServlet requested and no ContextLoaderListener registered

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, tomcat

I found several questions with same issue except for the fact that I am using an embedded tomcat.

I tried all answers I found, most of them related to ContextLoaderListener and dependencies.

I noted that when I builded the application after "mvn clean package" there are several warnnings about duplication but honestly I don't think this is the issue. I believe there is some issue between embedded Tomcat configuration and the context.

logs during buiding

```
C:\STS\wsRestTemplate\TestDeployment>mvn clean package
...
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ TestDeployment ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\STS\wsRestTemplate\TestDeployment\target\embeddedApp.jar

[INFO]
[INFO] --- appassembler-maven-plugin:1.10:assemble (default) @ TestDeployment --
-
[WARNING] The usage of program name (App) is deprecated. Please use program.id i
nstead.
[INFO] Installing artifact C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\s
pring-web\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar to C:\STS\wsRestTemplate\Te
stDeployment\target\repo\org\springframework\spring-web\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-web
-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[INFO] Installing artifact C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\s
pring-aop\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar to C:\STS\wsRestTemplate\Te
stDeployment\target\repo\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-aop
-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
...
[INFO] Installing artifact C:\STS\wsRestTemplate\TestDeployment\target\embeddedA
pp.jar to C:\STS\wsRestTemplate\TestDeployment\target\repo\com\mastercard\ictt\b
atchs\TestDeployment\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\TestDeployment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:1.3.3:shade (default) @ TestDeployment ---
[INFO] Including org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE in the shaded
jar.
[INFO] Including org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE in the shaded
...[INFO] Including commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/apache/jasper/Constants.class in C:\Users\e049
447\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper\8.0.32\tomcat-jasper-8.0.32.j
ar
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/apache/jasper/EmbeddedServletOptions.class in
C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper\8.0.32\tomcat-ja
sper-8.0.32.jar
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/apache/jasper/JasperException.class in C:\User
s\e049447\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper\8.0.32\tomcat-jasper-8.
0.32.jar
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/apache/jasper/JspC.class in C:\Users\e049447\.
m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper\8.0.32\tomcat-jasper-8.0.32.jar
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/apache/jasper/JspCompilationContext.class in C
:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper\8.0.32\tomcat-jas
per-8.0.32.jar
```

[image: Project Structure and Libs Dependencies]

[image: The error]

App-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycomp.myapp.batchs.AuthFileUpload" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="multipartResolver"
              class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

       <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

       <!-- I tried add COntextLoader Listener and explicitly point to App-servlet.xml but I don~t think it is necessary
       By the way, same error with it or without -->
       <!-- listener>
              <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
       </listener>

       <context-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>/WEB-INF/App-servlet.xml</param-value>
              </context-param -->

       <servlet>
              <servlet-name>App</servlet-name>
                           <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

              <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>

       <servlet-mapping>
              <servlet-name>App</servlet-name>
              <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
       <welcome-file-list>
              <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
       </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

static main

```
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;


public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws LifecycleException
    {
              Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

              tomcat.setPort(8080);
              tomcat.setBaseDir("C\\temp");
              tomcat.addWebapp(tomcat.getHost(), "/", "C:\\temp\\");//
              tomcat.start();
              tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

Index.jsp (if I comment all the lines below and I add a simple Hello Word string it will work as wellcome page)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Uploading a file.. </h2>
      <form:form method="POST" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              Upload your file please:
              <input type="file" name="file" />
              <input type="text" name="name">
              <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
              <form:errors path="file" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" />
       </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {


       @RequestMapping(value="/upload",method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
             return "index";
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your servlet mapping in web.xml. Acccording to the servlet spec the mapping / overrides the container`s default servlet. This means that your DispatcherServlet maps to all requests which have no explicit mapping. However the .jsp extension is mapped to the container`s jsp servlet. Hence index.jsp does not go through the DispatcherServlet hence you cannot use the spring form taglib there.

Instead implement a controller for your index.jsp so that it goes through dispatcher servlet

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController{

  @RequestMapping(value = "/")
  public String welcome(){
     return "index";
  }
}
```

Then move your index.jsp to WEB-INF folder to match your ViewResolver settings.
Then remove the

```
<welcome-file-list>
              <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
       </welcome-file-list>
```

in web.xml

Comment: Sorry, what you told me made a lot sense but now I am getting 404 when I try localhost:8080. It seems to me that App-servlet.xml isn't taking in account. Do you see anything missed in the way I am starting the application (kindly look at the main method)

Answer (score 0):

```
if your application context xml file name is App-servlet.xml then you need to pass its name as init param to the servlet

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>App</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/App-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>App</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`enter code here`
```

Comment: I did it and it keep same error. Kindly note that the error point to the 7th line which stands for "<form:form method="POST" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">". My best guess is that App-servlet.xml isn't being taken in account. Please, see the folders structure and the main method and let me know if you think I am missing something.